# Gdb export import memory

Tags: c++, gdb, heap-memory

Is there an option to export a memory snapshot and then import it again later?

For example I have a core file from a crash I had

There is an interesting stl string on frame #12 and I want to save the sting's data to a file
The data is binary and is very large

Then I want to run the original binary file with gdb and put a break point on the function from frame #12
and load the data I saved to the string.

This way I can reproduce the error, and step it through with gdb until the crash occurs

BTW, I was able to print out the data to log file because that string represents an array

1. I went down to frame #11
2. Printed the vector's content to a log file
3. Synthetically produced the array in the original code
4. compile it and ran it
5. I found the error and fixed it

Except this is a manual way and it took me forever

I am not looking for an alternative solution since I already solved the bug.

I want to know if gdb has an export/import memory option, and if so how to export import stl strings whose data is on the heap?

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to [generate another corefile](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Core-File-Generation.html) in gdb:

```
gcore dump.core
```

Then navigate to the same region in memory in a hex editor and compare the two. Alternatively, you can run `info proc mappings` to get a list of memory ranges, find the starting and ending address of the heap, then [manually dump that memory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html) with:

```
dump binary memory dumpfile heapstart heapend
```

where `heapstart` and `heapend` are the addresses you found.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if gdb has an export/import memory option, and if so how to export import stl strings whose data is on the heap?

You can use `dump memory filename.out addr1 addr2` to save contents of memory between `addr1` and `addr2` into a file. That's your "export". I just verified that that works for `core` target.

To "import" that data into a live process, you can simply call `read`. Assuming `$addr` is a sufficiently large heap buffer:

```
(gdb) set fd = open("filename.out", 0)
(gdb) call read($fd, $addr, $len)
(gdb) call close($fd)
```

Since the last one requires 3 commands, if this is something you want to do regularly, define a (user-defined) command for it.